# Can I access a Sharepoint calendar using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need to extract events from a shared calendar on SharePoint.

Using Microsoft Graph I've found the calendar:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/company.sharepoint.com/lists/CALENDAR_ID

Which includes a list array. I then tried:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/company.sharepoint.com/lists/CALENDAR_ID/list

Which returns:

```
 [_decodedBody:Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse:private] => Array
    (
        [@odata.context] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('company.sharepoint.com')/lists('CALENDAR_ID')/list
        [contentTypesEnabled] => 1
        [hidden] => 
        [template] => events
    )
```

There are no events listed. I've also tried **/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items** as shown on [Microsoft's API reference docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint). This does not show the events. Is it possible to extract the events this way?

Answer (score 0):

First, for question you've mentioned "**/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items**"
This is only available in graph api beta version, and yes, don't use it in production version of your product.

[image]

```
https://.sharepoint.com/site//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Calendar')/items
```

Please try the above code to retrieve your calendar items.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> There are no events listed. I've also tried
>   /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items as shown on Microsoft's API
>   reference docs. This does not show the events

most likely it occurs since *Item Level permissions* is enabled per Calendar.

**How to verify**

- Go to  Calendar settings in SharePoint UI:
  `/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={list-id}`
- under `Advanced Settings` verify whether `Read items that were
  created by the user` is selected

[image]

If `Read items that were created by the user` option is selected, then endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items`  will only return events that has been created by *current user*

---

In order to return *all* the events the following options could be considered:

1) disable Item-level Permissions per Calendar by setting it to `Read all items`

2) or utilize SharePoint API endpoint to retrieve all events: `https://server/_api/web/lists/getbyid('<list-id>')/items`

Depending on user permissions, you might need to enable `Override List Behaviors` permission level

[image]

otherwise users with restricted permissions will not be able to retrieve all the events